# DHCP setting an IP on router but APIPA on computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp, network-adapter

I took my computer with me while house sitting. Now back at home, DHCP is setting an IP on the router, but I get a `169.x.x.x` IP on the computer.

I've tried using a static IP but was unable to connect to the router. I've also tried different cables and ports on the router, but with no effect. Is there anything else I can try? I'm guessing the onboard NIC is not working.

Comment: Please provide details about the environment (windows, mac, linux) and if you can an ipconfig/ifconfig readout of the adapter you are using. Even better would be a readout of tcpdump -i interface port 67 when you connect the computer to the router (this will give the handoff between the computer and the router for DHCP to see what is happening) - if you are on windows, you can get it here: http://www.microolap.com/products/network/tcpdump/.

Comment: Sorry it's a windows 7 64bit box, I'm not at home so I can't give any readouts at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, I would guess this is a problem with the NIC on your computer.

I have had many computers just randomly fail and not being able to connect for random unknown reasons.

What fixes it 75% of the time for me is going in to device manager and uninstalling the device/choosing remove. I then scan for new hardware and let it reinstall, and it appears to work fine.

All I can guess is it fails due to corrupt settings stored in the registry or elsewhere.

The other 25% of the time, I was never able to fix it and I had to add a PCI NIC :(

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Apparently not, shut down the comp and now it's not working anymore.

Comment: @Michael, All I can say is to try the same steps again.